# Python os.path.join() and "+" in string concatenation

Tags: python

If I want to use a path "a/b", what is the difference between
os.path.join("a/","b") and "a/"+"b"  ?

Like this:

[image: 1]

Comment: Please post the code as text.

Comment: There's *usually* no practical difference in many cases. But I bet there are OSes/filesystems where manually doing may fail.

Answer (score 1):

The separator character is OS dependent. If you're going to be using your script on both windows and, say, linux, you should use the `os.path.join` function.
It probably doesn't matter if you're going to keep your script on the same machine, but you could also use the `os.sep` function to get the current system's separator character: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep

In short, use `os.path.join` to keep your script multiplatform safe

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.path and its functions, which take care of OS-specific paths. Will work on Windows with backslashes '\' and Unix (including Mac OS X) with '/'.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('root', 'subdir', 'dir', 'filename.ext')
'root/subdir/dir/filename.ext'
```

Using os.path.join makes the statement OS-agnostic. Also it makes obvious to other people reading your code that you are working with file paths. People can quickly scan through the code and discover it's a file path intrinsically.